# A* using a Priority Queue

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, game

I've implemented an A* with a priority queue. I am not getting any performance issues in this little game that I am making but it would be interesting to know how to improve this.

I am doing a few o(n) searches in getNode & isSuccessorValid. I thought about using an unordered map and pointing to each node location but when erasing from the vector, that pointer might not be valid anymore.

Thank you in advance.

```
    struct PriorityQueueNode
{
    PriorityQueueNode(const glm::ivec2& position, const glm::ivec2& parentPosition, float g, float h);

    float getF() const;

    glm::ivec2 position;
    glm::ivec2 parentPosition;
    float g;
    float h;
};

const auto nodeCompare = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) -> bool { return b.getF() < a.getF(); };
class PriorityQueue : private std::priority_queue<PriorityQueueNode, std::vector<PriorityQueueNode>, decltype(nodeCompare)>
{
public:
    PriorityQueue(size_t maxSize)
        : priority_queue(nodeCompare),
        m_maxSize(maxSize),
        m_addedNodePositions()
    {
        c.reserve(maxSize);
    }

    size_t getSize() const
    {
        assert(c.size() == m_addedNodePositions.size());
        return c.size();
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        assert(c.empty() && m_addedNodePositions.empty() || !c.empty() && !m_addedNodePositions.empty());
        return c.empty();
    }

    bool contains(const glm::ivec2& position) const
    {
        return m_addedNodePositions.find(position) != m_addedNodePositions.cend();
    }

    const PriorityQueueNode& getTop() const
    {
        assert(!isEmpty());
        return top();
    }

    const PriorityQueueNode& getNode(const glm::ivec2& position) const
    {
        auto node = std::find_if(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), [&position](const auto& node) -> bool
        {
            return node.position == position;
        });

        assert(node != c.end());
        return (*node);
    }

    bool isSuccessorNodeValid(const PriorityQueueNode& successorNode) const
    {
        auto matchingNode = std::find_if(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), [&successorNode](const auto& node) -> bool
        {
            return successorNode.position == node.position;
        });

        return matchingNode != c.cend() && successorNode.getF() < matchingNode->getF();
    }

    void changeNode(const PriorityQueueNode& newNode)
    {
        assert(isSuccessorNodeValid(newNode) && contains(newNode.position));

        eraseNode(newNode.position);
        add(newNode);
    }

    void add(const PriorityQueueNode& node)
    {
        assert(!contains(node.position) && c.size() + 1 <= m_maxSize);

        push(node);
        m_addedNodePositions.insert(node.position);
    }

    void popTop()
    {
        assert(!isEmpty());

        auto iter = m_addedNodePositions.find(top().position);
        assert(iter != m_addedNodePositions.end());
        m_addedNodePositions.erase(iter);

        pop();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        c.clear();
        m_addedNodePositions.clear();
    }

private:
    const size_t m_maxSize;
    std::unordered_set<glm::ivec2> m_addedNodePositions;

    void eraseNode(const glm::ivec2& position)
    {
        auto node = std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), [&position](const auto& node)
        {
            return node.position == position;
        });
        assert(node != c.cend());

        m_addedNodePositions.erase(position);
        c.erase(node);
    }
};
```

Comment: Post your A* algorithm as well to see if there any bottlenecks there. It's not clear how do you use your priority queue. For now i can only see not really performance affecting tweaks like using `set.count` instead of `std::find`. Also it probably won't compile even if glm structs will be in scope, because i can't see any definitions of what `c` is.

Comment: As noted by @Sugar the definition of `c` is not included in the question, this makes the code in the question extremely difficult to review.